# Выборка из базы записей, где в текстовом поле больше 50 русских символов и цифр

Tags: mysql, sql

Приветствую. В табличке есть поле `text` с таким же типом. Требуется выбрать все записи, где в этом поле хранится более 50 русских символов и цифр. Смотрел rexexp в mysql, но не совсем понял их принцип работы по примерам, особенно как вставить rexexp в where условие.

Comment: regexp поставить в where легко `'строка' regexp 'рег-выражение'`. Я бы даже регулярку которая сработает на нужное кол-во русских букв разбавленых латинскими сделал. Если бы не одно НО. regexp в MySQL не дружит с UTF8 в итоге она один русский символ будет считать за два. и вообще regexp в MySQL  русским языком дает непредсказуемые результаты. Например определенные комбинации русских букв вдруг перестают попадать в диапазон `[а-я]`, приходится разбивать диапазон на `[а-пр-я]` тогда лучше попадают

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(text) > 50
```

Comment: спасибо, но я думаю это не совсем то, в этом поле может также храниться латиница, пробелы, знаки препинания и тд, а нужно выбрать ли те где больше 50 РУССких символов и ЦИФР

Comment: @Vadim.K средствами mysql вы вряд ли это сделаете

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что нормальное решение только через написание функции, типа этой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468660/272885

Просто для фана: 
Если строка в UTF-8 состоит только из кириллицы и символов набора ASCII, то

Число кириллических символов:
`LENGTH(s) - CHAR_LENGTH(s)`

Число упоминаний '1':
`CHAR_LENGTH(s) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(s, '1', ''))`

Совмещаем всё это и получаем:

```
SELECT 
  LENGTH(s) - CHAR_LENGTH(s) +
  CHAR_LENGTH(s) - CHAR_LENGTH(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                      REPLACE(s, '1', ''), 
                    '2', ''),
                  '3', ''),
                '4', ''),
              '5', ''),
            '6', ''),
          '7', ''),
        '8', ''),
      '9', ''), 
    '0', '')
  ) AS cnt
FROM mytable
HAVING cnt > 50
```

Я использовад HAVING вместо WHERE чтобы сослаться на вычисляемое поле из фразы SELECT. MySQL такое позволяет.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4263e0/4

Надеюсь вам понравилось!

Comment: спасибо, интересный вариант. Сделал через php, ибо так намного проще

Answer (score 0):

Написать по одному REPLACE на каждую русскую букву (34, если не забыл), заменив её на пустую строку (''). Отобрать те записи, у которых разность длин исходной строки и преобразованной > 50.